# Angular event 'ng-click' binding issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I am having problem with angular **ng-Click**.

My Controller

```
var ParentController = function ( ) {

    this.MyEvent = function () {
        alert('foo-bar');
    };

    this.AddHTML= function () {
       $("#ButtonSec").html('<input type='button' ng-click='Parent.MyEvent()' value='inner button'/>');
    };
};

angular.module('myApp', []).controller('ParentController', ParentController);
```

HTML - 1 (Works as expected button ng-click binds to 'inner button' as expected):

```
<div ng-app='testComponent'>
     <div id="content" ng-controller="ParentController as Parent">
       <div id="ButtonSec">
            <input type='button' ng-click='Parent.MyEvent()' value='inner button'/>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

HTML-2 (Not working):When rendering html using Add HTML button. Event not binding to inner button as it should (important thing I can't use $scope as per client requirement)

```
<div ng-app='testComponent'>
     <div id="content" ng-controller="ParentController as Parent">
       <div id="ButtonSec">

       </div>
       <input type='button' ng-click='Parent.AddHTML()' value='Add HTML'/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: second one is out of the `Parent ` controller scope. Angular controller scope is only applicable for inner content and itself only

Comment: updated please do check... thanks

Comment: Have you included jQuery?

Comment: direct DOM manipulation will not work. You will have to use $compile service

Comment: @Samir 38 yes I also think some $compile sort of thing i have to do.. Can you tell me how run $compile angular compile and it would be much better if there is any way to compile only a specific html section. Like we $scope.$$apply() when using $scope but here we are not using $scope so i need to know equivalent to that.

Comment: @Zee -  yes i have included jquery.

Comment: Is it event entering `AddHTML()`? Can you place an `alert()` and confirm?

Comment: $compile need a scope as well. You should bypass using directive like ng-if or custom one

Comment: @Zee yes i have checked it works all the way except dynamic one. :(

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to use `ng-if` directive which will add or remove html on the `Expression` which we will provide to it. To showing hiding that div you need to maintain one variable inside your controller context that will be responsible for showing that div on html.

**Html**

```
<div ng-app='testComponent'>
     <div id="content" ng-controller="ParentController as Parent">
       <div ng-if="Parent.showContent" id="ButtonSec">
           <input type='button' ng-click='Parent.MyEvent()' value='inner button'/>
       </div>
       <input type='button' ng-click='Parent.showContent = true' value='Add HTML'/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I welcome your suggestion actually my requirement is a bit complex we have to make a section which will work as an editor where we will be adding svg files later on. This all should be dynamic as user is going to create a custom design same as MS- paint (but not that much :P).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you don't want to use $scope because angular manage $scope  eventually internally. This is hack way using $rootScope

```
var ParentController = function ($compile,$rootScope ) {

     this.MyEvent = function () {
         alert('foo-bar');
     };

     this.AddHTML= function () {
     $("#ButtonSec").html($compile("<input type='button' ng-click='Parent.MyEvent()'  value='inner button'/>")($rootScope.$$childHead));
     };
 };
```

Comment: @pankajparkar Because he want

Comment: you need to really look at this http://ng-learn.org/2014/01/Dom-Manipulations..we are not here to guide incorrect to OP,

Comment: Thank you for the advice. Have you ever read the user question? Have you seen my conversation with user under comment section?